# Trying to create a difference between admin login and user login

Tags: php

```
if($_SESSION['userid'] == 1)
{
    $_SESSION['admin'];
    header('location:admin.php');
}



else if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    $_SESSION['user'] = $username;
    header('location:logoutpage.php');

} else {

    header('location:login.php');

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is allowing the admin to have a session called admin and a user having a session called user.

Comment: Why?  Why not just have a single session variable that tells if they are an admin or regular user?  $_SESSION['access'] = "admin" or $_SESSION['access'] = "user"

Comment: Is something not working from what you have tried?

Comment: its redirecting me straight to the logoutpage. meaning that it is setting me up in a user session

Comment: If it is sending you to the logout page then $_SESSION['userid'] is not equal to 1.  Have you tried echoing it to see what is being stored?

Comment: This `if($_SESSION['userid'] == 1)
{ $_SESSION['admin'];` doesn't do much.

Answer (score 0):

During creation of the session add one variable  `$_SESSION['userType']='admin';` for admin and similarly   `$_SESSION['userType']='user';` for normal user.